# ThirdWeb Error: The address you're trying to send a transaction to is not a smart contract

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, smartcontracts, thirdweb

I am trying to create a Crowdfunding Dapp. I've deployed the smart contract on goerli testnet ([link](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x3A1e1F275E50810EE30b19517938D5d23a991802)). Now I created the frontend using react and connected it to the contract using thirdweb.

The contract has a function createCampaign() which is pretty simple
NOTE : there is a mapping called campaigns (mapping(uint256 => Campaign) public campaigns;) read the full source on the link above.

```
function createCampaign(
        address _owner,
        string memory _title,
        string memory _description,
        uint256 _target,
        uint256 _deadline,
        string memory _image
    ) public returns (uint256) {
        Campaign storage campaign = campaigns[numberOfCampaigns];

        require(
            campaign.deadline < block.timestamp,
            "The deadline should be a date in the future."
        );

        campaign.owner = _owner;
        campaign.title = _title;
        campaign.description = _description;
        campaign.target = _target;
        campaign.deadline = _deadline;
        campaign.amountCollected = 0;
        campaign.image = _image;

        numberOfCampaigns++;

        return numberOfCampaigns - 1;
    }
```

in the frontend I've created component which renders a form to get the values.
I've connected to the contract using thirdweb in this way

```js
const { contract } = useContract(
    "0x3A1e1F275E50810EE30b19517938D5d23a991802",
    ABI
  );
  const { mutateAsync: createCampaign } = useContractWrite(
    contract,
    "createCampaign"
  );

  const address = useAddress();
  const connect = useMetamask();

  const publishCampaign = async (form) => {
    console.log(`Address : ${address}`);
    try {
      const data = await createCampaign([
        address, // owner
        form.title, // title
        form.description, // description
        form.target,
        new Date(form.deadline).getTime(), // deadline,
        form.image,
      ]);

      console.log("contract call success", data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("contract call failure", error);
    }
  };
```

this is being passed as context to that component so that I can use createCampaign() .
in the component after the button press the code executed is

```js
await createCampaign({
          ...form,
          target: ethers.utils.parseUnits(form.target, 18),
        });
```

when clicking the button I am getting an error which says "contract call failure Error: The address you're trying to send a transaction to is not a smart contract. Make sure you are on the correct network and the contract address is correct"

I read the documentation for thirdweb, cant seem to figure out.

- I followed the documentation of thirdweb and couldnt find anything
- nothing on stackoverflow too.
- tried redeploying the contract but nothing.
- tried changing the contract and then redeploying

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you don't have enough ethereum to pay the gas fee.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer

Answer (score 0):

I also saw this error. You need to set `activeChain` in your `ThirdwebProvider` to solve this.